# Matlab 2016a legend line width

Tags: matlab, legend

I want to plot the legend in a Matlab figure using R2016a. Sample paint image left is what I get right is what I want:

[image: Sample paint image left is what i get rigth is what i want]

But the lines inside the legend box are too narrow. How can i make them longer?

Note that I am using Matlab 2016a. I cant get the legend properties and change them with code since when I type:

lgh=legend;

I get that lgh is a matlab.graphics.illustrator. Legend and when I double click it I go to the property inspector where I cant change the width of the lines inside the legend.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create an object, you could simply type in >> legend on 
on the command window, and legend will be added on the active plot.

Comment: I know the way to add a legend to active plot. The question is on an active legend on an active plot how can i make the lines of the legend that refer to the lines of the plot wider so they are more clearly visible and distinguishable.